# returning the correct height of custom drawing text method

Tags: iphone, quartz-2d

I have a few functions that I'm using to draw different type of text.  For example:

```
- (CGFloat)drawInformation:(CGContextRef)c withLeftCol:(NSArray *)leftCol rightcol:(NSArray *)rightCol atPoint:(CGPoint)point withLineSpacing:(CGFloat)lineSpacing {
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGFloat fontSize = 16.0;
    UIFont *pFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:fontSize];

    CGFloat yOffset = 0;
    for (NSString *leftColStr in leftCol) {
        [leftColStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(point.x, point.y + yOffset) withFont:pFont];
        yOffset += lineSpacing;
    }

    yOffset = 0;
    for (NSString *rightColStr in rightCol) {
        [rightColStr drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(rtStart, point.y + yOffset) withFont:pFont];
        yOffset += lineSpacing;
    }
    return [leftCol count] > [rightCol count] ? [leftCol count] * (fontSize + lineSpacing) : [rightCol count] * (fontSize + lineSpacing);
}
```

I didn't include the whole method, but this is the gist of it.  I basically take in an array of text, and draw them in two columns.  I want to return the height of the area so I know how large it is and can draw the next piece of text below it.

One thing I found is even though I set my `fontSize = 16`, if I do a `[@"text" sizeWithFont:pFont]`, I actually get 18 or something.  As you can see, I add in some `lineSpacing` as well.  So what I'm wondering is if I'm returning the correct amount in this case, and also, if I should be using the fontSize, or the `[@"text" sizeWithFont:pFont].height` in my return statement.  In its current state, when I need to draw my next block of text at the new point, it is pretty off, like 100 points, and I'm not sure why there is such a discrepancy.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate variables for the y offset in your first loop and the y offset in your second loop.  Then return `MAX(yOffsetLeftCol, yOffsetRightCol)`.